# How can I add an image of a cart in my navigation using only css?

Tags: css, image, cart, navigationbar, weebly

I'd like to add an image of a cart next to my cart item in my navigation bar. Is there any way of doing this using only css? I thought maybe a :after {} somewhere would work.

Here is the link to my site: http://poloniafoods.weebly.com/store/c1/Featured_Products.html

Thanks in advance,
Justin.

Comment: After would work, or you can do it as the css background.

Comment: At the same time this Q&A could be quite helpful for beginner coders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an after tag to the cart li element. Use content with a url to point to an absolut path of an image. Play with the size and positioning depending on your desired outcome.

```
.wsite-nav-cart:after {
    content: url('http://placehold.it/50');
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it to just use font awesome icons. Just use this code wherever you need it to be.

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and if you want to increase the size of the cart. just add an additional class `fa-2x`

and yeah, you need to use the font awesome icon's cdn.

Just go to their website and you'll get the cdn. Just add it like this before your `<html>` tag like the below script tag.

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/someUniqueId.js"></script>
```

[this is their site](http://fontawesome.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a background image in CSS.

E.g.

```
#wsite-nav-cart-a {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/n/G/6/h/white-shopping-cart-md.png) 2px 8px no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

I would suggest making a class rather than using this ID.